Implementing BLS Verification using the precompile altbn_128 contract
I am trying to implement BLS using the alt_bn128 curve.
so far my code looks as follows:
    function verify(
    uint256[2] memory signature,
    uint256[4] memory pubkey,
    uint256[2] memory message
    ) internal view returns (bool) {
        uint256[12] memory input = [signature[0], signature[1], nG2x1, nG2x0, nG2y1, nG2y0, message[0], message[1], pubkey[1], pubkey[0], pubkey[3], pubkey[2]];
        uint256[1] memory out;
        bool success;
        // solium-disable-next-line security/no-inline-assembly
        assembly {
            success := staticcall(sub(gas(), 2000), 8, input, 384, out, 0x20)
            switch success
            case 0 {
                invalid()
            }
        }
        require(success, "");
        return out[0] != 0;
    }


However this code returns success as false... I have no idea why the call to the precompile fails

Ethereum does not have a precompile that supports BLS signatures yet. Though, there is a proposal for it to be added on the next upgrade: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2537
